# How to refactor complicated SQL query which is broken

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Here is the simplified model of the domain

[image]

In a nutshell, unit grants documents to to a customer. There are two types of units: main units and their child units. Both belong to the same province, and to one province may belong multiple cities. Document has numerous events (processing history). Customer belongs to one city and province.

I have to write query, which returns **random** set of documents, given a target main unit code. Here is the criteria:

- Return 10 documents where the newest event_code = 10
- Each document must belong to a **different** customer living in any city of the unit's region (prefer different cities)
- Return the Customers newest Document which meets the criteria
- There **must** be both document types present in the result
- Result (customers chosen) should be **random** with each query

But...

- If there's not enough customers, try to use multiple documents of the same customer as a last resort
- If there aren't enough documents either, return as much as possible
- If there's not a single instance of another document type, then return all the same

There may be million of rows, and the query must be as fast as possible, it is executed frequently.

I'm not sure how to structure this kind of complex query in a sane manner. I'm using *Oracle* and *PL/SQL*. Here is something I tried, but it isn't working as expected (returns wrong data). How should I refactor this query and get the random result, and also honor all those borderline rules? I'm also worried about the performance regarding the joins and wheres.

```
CURSOR c_documents IS
WITH documents_cte AS
    SELECT d.document_id AS document_id, d.create_dt AS create_dt,
      c.customer_id 
    FROM documents d
    JOIN customers c ON (c.customer_id = d.customer_id AND
      c.province_id = (SELECT region_id FROM unit WHERE unit_code = 1234))
    WHERE exists (
       SELECT 1 
       FROM event 
       where document_id = d.document_id AND
         event_code = 10 
         AND create_dt = 
            SELECT MAX(create_dt) 
            FROM event 
            WHERE document_id = d.document_id)
SELECT * FROM documents_cte d
WHERE create_dt = (SELECT MAX(create_dt) 
                   from documents_cte
                   WHERE customer_id = d.customer_id)
```

How to correctly make this query with efficiency, randomness in mind? I'm not asking for exact solution, but guidelines at least.

Comment: What's the relationship between documents and events? I don't see a common field name. Actually I don't see a lot of corresponding field names.

Comment: IIRC, mysql doesn't have CTEs.

Comment: @jbrahy I just forgot to include the foreign keys in the picture. As you can see there is one-to-many relationship between them

Comment: So regions are actually just two levels; provinces and their cities? I can detect a city by either looking at its type or by noticing that it has a parent_region. And I can detect a province by either looking at its type or by noticing that it has no parent_region. Correct? So only two levels with redundant type informations. I will find a province for every city. Is all this correct?

Comment: this is correct

Comment: The rules are not consistent. "Return the Customers newest Document which meets the criteria". Let's say I find 20 documents matching the criteria and all of these have document type A. Then: "There must be both document types present in the result". This would not be the case. So what to do in this situation?

Comment: And just to make sure I understood correctly: Unit has a region_id and this region_id can either be the region_id of a city or of a province. Yes? For the query I get a unit code and thus get to a city directly or to a province from which I get to the province's cities. Of this city or these cities I take the customers and of these the documents. Correct?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid hierarchic tables whenever possible. In your case you are using a hierarchic table to allow for an unlimited depth, but at last it's just two levels you store: provinces and their cities. That should better be just two tables: one for provinces and one for cities. Not a big deal, but that would make your data model simpler and easier to query.

Below I am starting with a `WITH` clause to get a city table, as such doesn't exist. Then I go step by step: get the customers belonging to the unit, then get their documents and rank them. At last I select the ranked documents and randomly take 10 of the best ranked ones.

```
with cities as
(
  select
    c.region_id as city_id,
    o.region_id as province_id
  from region c
  join region p on p.region_id = c.parent_region_id
)
, unit_customers as
(
  select customer_id
  from customer
  where city_id in
  (
    select city_id
    from cities
    where 
    (
      select region_id
      from unit
      where unit_code = 1234
    ) in (city_id, province_id)
  )
)
, ranked_documents as
(
  select
    document.*,
    row_number(partition by customer_id order by create_dt desc) as rn
  from document
  where customer_id in -- customers belonging to the unit
  (
    select customer_id 
    from unit_customers
  )
  and document_id in -- documents with latest event code = 10
  (
    select document_id
    from event 
    group by document_id
    having max(event_code) keep (dense_rank last order by create_dt) = 10
  )
)
select *
from ranked_documents
order by rn, dbms_random.value
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

This doesn't take into account to get both document types, as this contradicts the rule to get the latest documents per customer.

`FETCH FIRST` is availavle as of Oracle 12c. In earlier versions you would use one more subquery and another `ROW_NUMBER` instead.

As to speed, I'd recommend these indexes for the query:

```
create index idx_r1 on region(region_id); -- already exists for region_id = primary key
create index idx_r2 on region(parent_region_id, region_id);
create index idx_u1 on unit(unit_code, region_id);
create index idx_c1 on customer(city_id, customer_id);
create index idx_e1 on event(document_id, create_dt, event_code);
create index idx_d1 on document(document_id, customer_id, create_dt);
create index idx_d2 on document(customer_id, document_id, create_dt);
```

One of the last two will be used, the other not. Check which with `EXPLAIN PLAN` and drop the unused one.